# React refresh a page with combined route (that includes parameters) from a deployed war

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have such a route in my home page:

```
<Route exact path="/editProject/:project/:type/:fabConfig" render={(props)=>
                            <ProjectEditor project={props.match.params.project}
                                           fabConfig={props.match.params.fabConfig}
                                           history= {this.props.history}/>
                        } />
```

The url is combined with some parameters like: project name, project type, etc..
When working on dev mode, and doing refresh manually to a page with such url it's working as expected.

But when deploying the build artifacts within a war (on tomcat), and doing the same getting an empty page.

Is there a way to handle it without blocking the Refresh\Back buttons of the browser?

## UPDATE

I tried switching my approach and using a simple URL with "/editProject" only.
Regarding the parameters to send them by emit event:

```
async openProjectEditor() {
    // EventsDispatcher.openProject(this.props.project.Name, this.props.project.Type, this.confDefaultValue)
    // this.props.history.push('/editProject/')

    await this.emitOpenProject()
    this.props.history.push('/editProject/')
}

emitOpenProject () {
    return new Promise(() => {
        EventsDispatcher.openProject(this.props.project.Name, this.props.project.Type, this.confDefaultValue)
    })
}
```

But I never reach the line after `await this.emitOpenProject()` !
I reached out to implement it as async cause when i was redirecting to EditProject component it wasn't reaching the event method, so I though it might be related to the fact that emit didn't finish yet.

I even tried to implement a [Promisify eventEmitter](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/promisify-event-emitter/) but not reaching "then" clause at all!

What can be the reason? The fact that the EditProject component is not loaded yet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its due to the nature of client-side routing. For example, when you deployed your website and tried to go to a specific path before loading homepage, you will get an empty page because without going to homepage, your site can not get all the javascript it needs to render the rest of your site paths. This can be solved by serving your react app with an express server, and in express, for every route you always send the index.html in build folder so the page will load all the js files it need

Comment: Sounds interesting, but as I understood express server is a node.js server side and my war is a java jars wrapper with the outcome of client javascript generated and located under WEB-INF. instead I tried implementing something else (refer to UPDATE section in my post), the problem with it that it's never comes back from await!